# How to show multiple items in kivy carousel?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to do a carousel of image/buttons to show more than one item at time.

Like the demo in the url:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick/

[image]

Any ideas of how can i do that.

Comment: You could approximate something like that with a horizontal `ScrollView`.  Otherwise you could write your own widget to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it with a `ScrollView`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button

kv = '''
<MyButt>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 250, 250
BoxLayout:
    pos_hint: {'top': 1}
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    Label:
        text: 'One At A Time'
        size_hint: 1, None
        font_size: 50
        height: 75
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: 250
        do_scroll_y: False
        BoxLayout:
            id: box
            size_hint_x: None
            width: self.minimum_width
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
'''


class MyButt(Button):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_buttons)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def add_buttons(self, dt):
        box = self.root.ids.box
        for i in range(25):
            # Add some widgets to the ScrollView
            box.add_widget(MyButt(text='Button ' + str(i)))

TestApp().run()
```